# I have a dual core machine. In java, how is a fixedThreadPool of 3 threads managed by my computer? What is a possible behavior of the jvm?

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm trying to visualize how my machine would behave with this code if its a dual core processor. How would it behave if it were a quad core machine?

```
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);

    // Submission of tasks
    for (int i =0; i<10; i++){
        executor.submit(new Processor(i));
    }
```

The Processor has a run method that prints "running in thread: about to sleep..." 
Then it sleeps for 5 seconds then prints "running in thread: woke up..."

I'm trying to connect the dots between java code and hardware. I'm having difficulty picturing how this differs in different processor environments. Could someone give an example of a possible behavior of the jvm in this situation? Thank you in advance.

Comment: The answer is going to depend somewhat on which operating system you're running.  Perhaps the Javadoc for the [ThreadPoolExecutor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html) class might help you determine what happens.

Comment: I would say that the only limit here is the number of threads, since your `Processor`s are mostly idle. So, I do not expect it to behave differently with two cores or with sixty-four. In the end, your 3 first tasks will launched while the rest are queued and, at intervals of barely 5 seconds, the 3 current tasks will end and three more will be started. There may be some difference in the order in which they are scheduled but it will depend mostly on the JVM/OS management of threads.

Comment: Between Java code and hardware is the Operating System which does a lot of the task scheduling - I found one [article with pictues](http://www.cs.uic.edu/~jbell/CourseNotes/OperatingSystems/4_Threads.html).

Comment: All these answers are just just sort of highlighting what I kind of already understand. I need a concrete possibility. I'm not even asking for the exact behavior. I need an example of POSSIBLE Behavior.

Answer (score 4):

The answer to each of your questions is, "yes". Or, to be less coy, the behavior you are asking for us  to document is <strike>undefined</strike> very deliberately only loosely defined.

The JVM and O/S, working together are free to run your threads in any order at any time, on whatever CPU/core is available when they are eligible to run, provided they sleep for at least 5 seconds between the `running` and `woke up` messages. Due to the nature of sleep, it will be at least that time, and the thread will awake as close to that time as the scheduler can manage.

Beyond that, there's not much more that can be said.

---

In response to the comment, the question's code will add 10 items to a task queue, and will dequeue up to three at a time(*) and run each group of three concurrently.

Because the execution time is dominated by the `sleep`, the behavior will be essentially identical no matter how many cores are available.

However, the exact order in which things will happen is non-deterministic, beyond the fact that the tasks will be pulled off in the order added. So while you can be certain that the 10th task will execute after the 1st, you can't be certain about the ordering of 1, 2 and 3, nor whether 4, 5 or 6 might start before 1, 2 or 3 has entirely finished.

(*) Up to three, because the last group will have only two items and the third thread will be idle while they run.

Comment: I'm actually looking for a more basic explanation of what the above code does with a dual core and a quad core procesor. I'm no asking for what happens, I'm asking for a possible behavior to understand what threading is all about.

Comment: Lawrence's answer is the best you are going to get. The interaction between threads and cores is undefined. At the native level, you can control thread-core affinity, but Java doesn't expose that. So with your program, it's just as possible that all 10 tasks execute on a single core as it is that they split. It's also possible that the various print commands of a given task run on *different* cores (the OS can flip a thread between cores if it wants). Most implementations will spread the the threads over the available cores - but that decision is transparent to us.

Comment: @TazMan It's basically summed up as "whatever the OS wants". It could decide to randomly pick 2 threads, run them to completion and then pick up the 3rd thread. It could decide to cycle through the threads two at a time giving each one a X millisecond time-slice. Another higher priority process could take up and occupy an entire core leaving the OS with only 1 core to schedule 3 threads.

Comment: @TazMan In a modern OS, there's basically a queue of all the threads in the system that are ready to run. And it will cycle through N (N = # of hardware threads) at a time giving each thread X milliseconds of run time before switching it out for the next one on the queue. The JVM threads of your app can be anywhere in that queue and are not distinguished from any other thread in the system aside from priority. Further reading: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_scheduler